# Methods to End Of File (EOF) not working in the NetBeans console

Tags: c, eof

[image: Code Image]

I have been learning C from K&Re2. And the above code is what is mentioned in Pg18(**Letter counting program**), which I ran for confirmation purposes. I tried entering few characters and press `ENTER`, but it was not working. Then I heard about `CTRL+Z`,`CTRL+C` or `CTRL+D` with `ENTER` for End Of File. I tried it in NetBeans console, but it was not working. I tried `\0` and `\n` too, pity it was not working too. I have searched for this, but all seemed to have solved the problem with `CTRL+Z`,`CTRL+C` or `CTRL+D` with `ENTER` method. I can't understand what is the problem here.
PS: I use Windows 7

Sorry for not inserting code directly. Here is it-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    long c = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF) {
        ++c;
    }
    printf("%ld", c);
    return 0;
}
```

In the image, I have not initialized value of `long c`. Sorry for that. This program is running, but the methods I use for EOF doesn't work out.

**EDIT:**
I have tried compiling in NetBeans, and then running the resulting .exe in cmd rather than in NetBeans console. `CTRL+Z` seems to work! Do you guys have any idea why it doesn't work in NetBeans console?

Comment: Do not post your code as image. Please post your code as text directly in your question. Also you invoked *undefined behavior* by using value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate.

Comment: Please specify your desired behavior.

Comment: I believe the code was working; you just haven't worked out how to indicate to a running program that there is no more data for it to read.  It looks like you're probably on a Windows platform.  If that's correct, Control-Z should indicate EOF.  You still need to initialize the counter (is that `c`?) to `0` before you start incrementing it: `long c = 0;`.  Are you sure K&R doesn't include an initialization or simply setting `c = 0;`?

Comment: I am sorry, I initialized it now. But still the program is running, but not displaying the number of characters in the input. Control Z is doing nothing...

Comment: If you are using windows, try _getch or _getche instead of getchar.  These are non-standard functions but it should do what you want.

Comment: Oh no problem. Thank you

Comment: An IDE's output window is not really a console. It can handle things like simple text output (for logging functionality usually), but beyond that, you should be launching a console program through a console. (Most?) IDEs don't have a way to send an `EOF` sequence for example, assuming it allows reading from `stdin` at all.

Comment: Yes of course usually IDEs open up cmd for running programs in C/C++. Don't know why NetBeans has Output window for C/C++ plugin

Answer (score 1):

`getchar()` stores characters in buffer until you press enter key. After enter key is pressed,first character is taken from buffer if no subsequent variable is being assigned.As you used `while` loop it will take until `\r\n`.so you have to press `enter key` + `ctrl+z` to reach EOF.

Comment: well yes it works in cmd. I tried the method and it seems to be perfect. Please see the Edit I made to the question. It doesnt work on NetBeans console.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Only

Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)

Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2

Run > Set project configuration > Customize...

Category = Run

Console Type = External Terminal

External Terminal Type = Command Window

Click Apply then OK

Run project

To send <kbd>EOF</kbd> press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd>  Or Press <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> twice